# How to read a BLE peripheral's model and serial number before connecting to it on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

The model and serial number of the BLE device I am interested in can be recognized by its company's iOS app during a Bluetooth scan. I also want my Android app to do it. The device has GATT characteristics for reading its model number string and serial number string. But I don't think the app can read from the GATT characteristics before connecting to the device as it needs authentication to read the characteristics and I didn't observe any read request from the iOS Bluetooth HCI log.

I think it is related to the advertising data(captured from iOS HCI log and viewed by Wireshark):

```
Advertising Data
    Device Name: $Randomly_generated_name
        Length: 6
        Type: Device Name (0x09)
        Device Name: $Randomly_generated_name
    Flags
        Length: 2
        Type: Flags (0x01)
        000. .... = Reserved: 0x0
        ...0 .... = Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host): false (0x0)
        .... 0... = Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Controller): false (0x0)
        .... .1.. = BR/EDR Not Supported: true (0x1)
        .... ..0. = LE General Discoverable Mode: false (0x0)
        .... ...1 = LE Limited Discoverable Mode: true (0x1)
    16-bit Service Class UUIDs
        Length: 7
        Type: 16-bit Service Class UUIDs (0x03)
        UUID 16: Battery Service (0x180f)
        UUID 16: Device Information (0x180a)
        UUID 16: Unknown ($Custom_UUID)
```

I cannot see any relevant information from this advertising data. Then I found out it also advertise(?) an extended inquiry response (EIR) from it's Bluetooth classic module:

```
Extended Inquiry Response Data
    Device Name: $Model_Abbreviation $Serial
        Length: 16
        Type: Device Name (0x09)
        Device Name: $Model_Abbreviation $Serial
    Tx Power Level
        Length: 2
        Type: Tx Power Level (0x0a)
        Power Level (dBm): 12
    16-bit Service Class UUIDs
        Length: 3
        Type: 16-bit Service Class UUIDs (0x03)
        UUID 16: Serial Port (0x1101)
    Unused
```

and coincidentally the device name has the information I need. But the only problem is these two data do not share the same mac address or any common identifier, I don't know which EIR belongs to which advertising data if there are multiple devices.

Or are there other approaches that can fulfill my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

For starters you're right, you can't perform any GATT operations without establishing a connection first. This is regardless of the fact that a read operation requires authentication first. It is more due to the fact that a GATT operation (read, write, subscribe, etc) happens over a connection link and cannot be performed via adverts.

Regarding the connection over the BLE transport after a classic link is established, the only thing that I can think of is if there is information that is being transferred over the classic link that is relevant for the BLE connection. For example, it is possible that once the classic Bluetooth connection is established, the LE mac address or the LE advert data is being sent from the remote device to the peer device. This would give the peer device something to look for when scanning for an LE device. The best way to check this is by using wireshark to sniff the communication between the two sides.

However, in all of this one thing that jumps to me as strange is the fact that the BLE advert packet shows that BR/EDR is not supported. This leads me to think that either there's an issue in the manufacturer's implementation of the Bluetooth technology (which should've been flagged by a Bluetooth qualification process) or maybe there's an issue with wireshark decoding the data, or finally maybe there's a human error in your process that is leading to you looking at different device packets. I would suggest that you spend some time to focus on why this issue exists in the first place as it might lead you to an obvious issue that will ultimately help you answer your question.

Comment: I cannot see any bluetooth classic packets from the iOS Bluetooth HCI log except that particular ERI data during a Bluetooth scan in the app. Would a affordable sniffer do better? I just have a nRF sniffer but it cannot handle BR/EDR packets.I also have a guess that the company could have a database of all their device mac address, serial number and model hidden in the app so they can search they data by mac address. The app need a free-registered account, thus Internet access is necessary, thus they could update that database for future devices too.